# How i can get first child element from xml?

Tags: php, xml, children, simplexml

How i can get first child element from `xml` in `PHP` my code :

```
    $xmlPath = 'www.example.com/file.xml';
    $fileContents= file_get_contents($xmlPath);

    $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", "<br>"), '', $fileContents);
      $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
      $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
      $xmlArray = array();
      foreach($simpleXml->children() as $child) {
        $xmlArray [] = array(
          'parent' => $child->getName(),
        );
        foreach($child->children() as $subchild) {
          $xmlArray[] = array(
            'child' => $subchild->getName()
          );
        }
      }
```

XML Code :

```
<root>
<urun>
<UrunID>9728</UrunID>
<Kod>3697-844 BORDO</Kod>
<Baslik>İRONİ KRUVAZE BORDO EKOSELİ ŞİFON BLUZ</Baslik>
<Renk>BORDO</Renk>
<Aciklama>Kumaş Bilgisi: %100 POLYESTER<br><br>Manken Ölçüleri: Göğüs : 85, Bel : 61, Kalça : 89, Boy:177<br><br>Mankenin Giydiği Beden: S/36</Aciklama>
<Durum>1</Durum>
<mainCategory>Kadın Giyim</mainCategory>
<subCategory>Bluz</subCategory>
<Marka>İroni</Marka>
<kdvHaricFiyat>9.17</kdvHaricFiyat>
<kdvDahilFiyat>9.90</kdvDahilFiyat>
<kdvDahilAlisFiyat>6.44</kdvDahilAlisFiyat>
<fiyatparabirimi>TL</fiyatparabirimi>
<KDV>8</KDV>
<link>
http://www.ironitekstil.com/urun/ironi-kruvaze-bordo-ekoseli-sifon-bluz_9728.aspx
</link>
<ImageName1>
http://www.ironitekstil.com/uploads/productsimages/3697-844-ironi-bordo-gomlek-1.jpg
</ImageName1>
<ImageName2>
http://www.ironitekstil.com/uploads/productsimages/3697-844-ironi-bordo-gomlek-3.jpg
</ImageName2>
<ImageName3>
http://www.ironitekstil.com/uploads/productsimages/3697-844-ironi-bordo-gomlek-2.jpg
</ImageName3>
<Kur>TL</Kur>
<StokAdedi>2</StokAdedi>
<Stoklar>
<stok>
<isim>BORDO</isim>
<deger>S</deger>
<barcode>1000000007077</barcode>
<miktar>0</miktar>
</stok>
<stok>
<isim>BORDO</isim>
<deger>XS</deger>
<barcode>1000000007619</barcode>
<miktar>2</miktar>
</stok>
<stok>
<isim>BORDO</isim>
<deger>M</deger>
<barcode>1000000007626</barcode>
<miktar>0</miktar>
</stok>
<stok>
<isim>BORDO</isim>
<deger>L</deger>
<barcode>1000000007633</barcode>
<miktar>0</miktar>
</stok>
<stok>
<isim>BORDO</isim>
<deger>XL</deger>
<barcode>3543000015973</barcode>
<miktar>0</miktar>
</stok>
</Stoklar>
<yeniSezon/>
</urun>
<urun>
<UrunID>9728</UrunID>
<Kod>3697-844 BORDO</Kod>
<Baslik>İRONİ KRUVAZE BORDO EKOSELİ ŞİFON BLUZ</Baslik>
<Renk>BORDO</Renk>
<Aciklama>Kumaş Bilgisi: %100 POLYESTER<br><br>Manken Ölçüleri: Göğüs : 85, Bel : 61, Kalça : 89, Boy:177<br><br>Mankenin Giydiği Beden: S/36</Aciklama>
<Durum>1</Durum>
<mainCategory>Kadın Giyim</mainCategory>
<subCategory>Bluz</subCategory>
<Marka>İroni</Marka>
<kdvHaricFiyat>9.17</kdvHaricFiyat>
<kdvDahilFiyat>9.90</kdvDahilFiyat>
<kdvDahilAlisFiyat>6.44</kdvDahilAlisFiyat>
<fiyatparabirimi>TL</fiyatparabirimi>
<KDV>8</KDV>
<link>
http://www.ironitekstil.com/urun/ironi-kruvaze-bordo-ekoseli-sifon-bluz_9728.aspx
</link>
<ImageName1>
http://www.ironitekstil.com/uploads/productsimages/3697-844-ironi-bordo-gomlek-1.jpg
</ImageName1>
<ImageName2>
http://www.ironitekstil.com/uploads/productsimages/3697-844-ironi-bordo-gomlek-3.jpg
</ImageName2>
<ImageName3>
http://www.ironitekstil.com/uploads/productsimages/3697-844-ironi-bordo-gomlek-2.jpg
</ImageName3>
<Kur>TL</Kur>
<StokAdedi>2</StokAdedi>
<Stoklar>
<stok>
<isim>BORDO</isim>
<deger>S</deger>
<barcode>1000000007077</barcode>
<miktar>0</miktar>
</stok>
<stok>
<isim>BORDO</isim>
<deger>XS</deger>
<barcode>1000000007619</barcode>
<miktar>2</miktar>
</stok>
<stok>
<isim>BORDO</isim>
<deger>M</deger>
<barcode>1000000007626</barcode>
<miktar>0</miktar>
</stok>
<stok>
<isim>BORDO</isim>
<deger>L</deger>
<barcode>1000000007633</barcode>
<miktar>0</miktar>
</stok>
<stok>
<isim>BORDO</isim>
<deger>XL</deger>
<barcode>3543000015973</barcode>
<miktar>0</miktar>
</stok>
</Stoklar>
<yeniSezon/>
</urun>
</root>
```

**So i want to get only first element how i can do that , any suggestion ?**

Comment: Please paste your xml code.

Comment: And first element is?

Comment: first element start with tag name `urun`

Comment: You can break your `foreach`. First element will be processed and with `break` other elements will be skipped.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question (which is possible, you weren't very clear), you have a loop over all child elements:

```
foreach($simpleXml->children() as $child) {
```

To change this to just access the first child element is really trivial:

```
$children = $simpleXml->children();
$first_child = $children[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

In SimpleXML:

```
$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$firstElementChild = $root->children()[0];
```

Or with Xpath:

```
$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$firstElementChild = $root->xpath('./*[1]')[0];
```

In DOM Level 2 (That is implemented in PHP ext/dom.)

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$context = $document->documentElement;

$firstElementChild = $xpath->evaluate('./*[1]', $context)[0];
```

The first approach uses that SimpleXML sees the DOM as a tree of nested elements. The other two use Xpath to fetch all element children and limit the result list to 1, then fetch the first element (index 0) from the result list.

In DOM Level 3 nodes with children have a `firstElementChild` property.

Comment: XPath always strikes me like regex: powerful, but overkill for a lot of cases. In this case, you can just get `$root->children()[0]` in SimpleXML; DOM is probably fiddlier, though.

Comment: You're right. I am just always thinking on nodes and sometimes forget that SimpleXML is more an element tree.

Comment: That's actually a pretty neat summary of the difference between SimpleXML and DOM (+ XPath etc), I must remember that.

Answer (score -1):

It 's simple with PHP 's own DomDocument.

```
$oXML = (new DomDocument())->load('path/to/your/file.xml');
$oElement = $oXML->getElementsByTagName('urun');
```

After that $oElement is a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) object over which you can iterate.

To get the content:

```
$oElement->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Obviously there is no content in the urun node. Only child nodes. In the DomNodeList $oElement includes all the content of the urun node. You can iterate over it. You can search for other nodes in it. It contains all the childnodes urun got.

Comment: it's not my case , i want to get it without  tag name

Comment: So you want the content of the node?

Comment: Obviously there is no content in the first urun node. There are only child nodes you can get by iterating over the retrieved DOMNodeList.

Comment: i've got an error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementByTagName()`

Comment: There was a typo in the code example. Edited it. Just have a look in the PHP documentation. You asked for fetching the first urun node. You got an example for fetching the first urun node. Now it 's up to you. Use it. Stack Overflow is not for begging for complete working code examples.